# Remove character for string without built in function

Tags: javascript

The function will check each letters of the strings and removes the character, which give in second parapeter. Every word first lettr must me capitalized. when the first letter of the string is removed. Your function would return the result as one array, where each element of array is separated by comma.
function([“Sonah”,”Himaliya”,”Sharma”], “a”);
// returns 'Sonh,Himliy,Shrm'

My code

```js
let arr = [“Sonah”,”Himaliya”,”Sharma”];

function asciiToCharacter(str, cha){
    var newStr = "";
    var alpha = "";
    
    for(let i=0;i<=str.length-1;i++){
        var name = str[i];
        for(let a=0; a<=str[i].length-1; a++){
            
            if(name[a] != cha){
                newStr += name[a];
            }

        }

        newStr += ','; 
    }
    console.log(newStr);
}

asciiToCharacter(arr,'h');
```

Comment: Do you have a question for us?

Comment: You never define `position`, to start with. Please try to minimise your code, as there's a lot of cruft that's... as far as I can tell doing nothing (loops that change an undefined value that has no influence on the output etc...). It's unclear what your current issue is and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Can we use UpperCase or LowerCase function?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ['John','Hannah','Saham','Hhahbhc','ahbhhch'];

function asciiToCharacter(str, cha){
  var newStr = "";
  var alpha = "";
  const upper = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  const lower = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  var index;

  for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    var name = str[i];
    var capital = false;
    for(let a=0; a<str[i].length; a++){
      var match = caseIntensiveCompare(name[a]);
      if (match) { continue; }
      if (capital) { newStr += name[a]; }
      else {
        newStr += upper[index];
        capital = true;
      }
    }
    if (i != str.length - 1) { newStr += ','; }
  }
  console.log(newStr);
  
  function caseIntensiveCompare(input) {
    for(let i=0; i<upper.length; i++) {
      if(input==lower[i] || input==upper[i]) { 
        index = i;
        if (lower[i]==cha) { return true; }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

asciiToCharacter(arr,'h');
```

Comment: You have a typo, `upper.ength`, which may be the reason this doesn't work -- **Edit**: This was not the reason this doesn't work

Comment: Corrected. It works now but there are ways to improve it.

Comment: So you need it to compact with string starts with lower case and string including non-alphabet characters?

Comment: Do you expect Upper case or non-alphabet for `cha`?

Comment: It now supports string starts with lower case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let arr = ["John", "Hannah", "Saham"];

function asciiToCharacter(array, cha) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].replace(cha, "");
  }
  console.log(array);
}

asciiToCharacter(arr, "h");
```

Comment: `replace` is a "built-in function".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some sort of homework question.

Shouldn't be hard to convert to not use built-in functions.

```js
function main(arr, char) {
  const regex = new RegExp(char, 'gi');
  const result = [];
  
  for (let str of arr) {
    //const shouldCapitalize = str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === char.toLowerCase();
    
    str = str.replace(regex, '');
    
    //if (shouldCapitalize) {
      result.push(str.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1));
    //} else result.push(str);
  }
  
  return String(result);
}
```

Comment: SharedRory i am trying without built in function .

Comment: @Harpreet Once again, I am not here to do your homework rather to help you. Your problem is that the letters can be a different case from the one passed in to the function. Either use .to[Lower/Upper]Case or have the user pass in both versions of the character and then compare it that way. Even if you choose this method, you would need the built-in functions to make the next char capital when the 1st gets removed.

Comment: Thanks SharedRory if i have to use built in function i can do it. not problem. I just want to know that how this program solve without built in function.